# Зависшие процессы Office interop

Tags: c#, office, office-interop

Предположим, в приложении необходимо использовать Office interop.(без вариантов)
Всем известно, что он создает приложения office без интерфейса и через них выполняет работу.

Ну как быть, если пользователь некорректно завершил работу с программой? Например, убил через диспетчер задач. Получается, что в процессах остаются висеть приложения офиса.

Можно ли это предотвратить? Если нет, то можно ли понять при запуске(повторном) приложения, что в процессах висит мусор, который остался от прошлого запуска и грохнуть эти процессы, не затронув реальные приложения офиса(например, юзер запустил Excel.)

Comment: `он создает приложения office без интерфейса` - по умолчанию как раз таки с интерфейсом, вроде же...

Comment: Не суть важно...

Answer (score 6):

Как вариант, средствами Win32 можно объединить приложение и запущенные из него процессы в задание ([Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx)) тогда процессы Interop будут завершаться вместе с родительским приложением.

Для этого нужно будет создать задание с помощью [`CreateJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682409(VS.85).aspx), а затем добавлять созданные процессы в задание с помощью [`AssignProcessToJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx)

Есть похожее обсуждение на английском языке: «[Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)». Из [ответа @Ron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed#37034966) можно взять код класса-обертки `ChildProcessTracker`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows processes to be automatically killed if this parent process unexpectedly quits.
/// This feature requires Windows 8 or greater. On Windows 7, nothing is done.</summary>
/// <remarks>References:
///  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657392/386091
///  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9164742/386091 </remarks>
public static class ChildProcessTracker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the process to be tracked. If our current process is killed, the child processes
    /// that we are tracking will be automatically killed, too. If the child process terminates
    /// first, that's fine, too.</summary>
    /// <param name="processHandle"></param>
    public static void AddProcess(int processHandle)
    {
        if (s_jobHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            bool success = AssignProcessToJobObject(s_jobHandle, new IntPtr(processHandle));
            if (!success)
                throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    static ChildProcessTracker()
    {
        // This feature requires Windows 8 or later. To support Windows 7 requires
        //  registry settings to be added if you are using Visual Studio plus an
        //  app.manifest change.
        //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232259/386091
        //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507862/386091
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version < new Version(6, 2))
            return;

        // The job name is optional (and can be null) but it helps with diagnostics.
        //  If it's not null, it has to be unique. Use SysInternals' Handle command-line
        //  utility: handle -a ChildProcessTracker
        string jobName = "ChildProcessTracker" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        s_jobHandle = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, jobName);

        var info = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            LimitFlags = JOBOBJECTLIMIT.JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE
        };

        // This is the key flag. When our process is killed, Windows will automatically
        //  close the job handle, and when that happens, we want the child processes to
        //  be killed, too.

        var extendedInfo = new JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION();
        extendedInfo.BasicLimitInformation = info;

        int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION));
        IntPtr extendedInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false);

            if (!SetInformationJobObject(s_jobHandle, JobObjectInfoType.ExtendedLimitInformation,
                extendedInfoPtr, (uint)length))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(extendedInfoPtr);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject(IntPtr lpJobAttributes, string name);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(IntPtr job, JobObjectInfoType infoType,
        IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, uint cbJobObjectInfoLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject(IntPtr job, IntPtr process);

    // Windows will automatically close any open job handles when our process terminates.
    //  This can be verified by using SysInternals' Handle utility. When the job handle
    //  is closed, the child processes will be killed.
    private static readonly IntPtr s_jobHandle;
}

public enum JobObjectInfoType
{
    AssociateCompletionPortInformation = 7,
    BasicLimitInformation = 2,
    BasicUIRestrictions = 4,
    EndOfJobTimeInformation = 6,
    ExtendedLimitInformation = 9,
    SecurityLimitInformation = 5,
    GroupInformation = 11
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
{
    public Int64 PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
    public Int64 PerJobUserTimeLimit;
    public JOBOBJECTLIMIT LimitFlags;
    public UIntPtr MinimumWorkingSetSize;
    public UIntPtr MaximumWorkingSetSize;
    public UInt32 ActiveProcessLimit;
    public Int64 Affinity;
    public UInt32 PriorityClass;
    public UInt32 SchedulingClass;
}

[Flags]
public enum JOBOBJECTLIMIT : uint
{
    JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE = 0x2000
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct IO_COUNTERS
{
    public UInt64 ReadOperationCount;
    public UInt64 WriteOperationCount;
    public UInt64 OtherOperationCount;
    public UInt64 ReadTransferCount;
    public UInt64 WriteTransferCount;
    public UInt64 OtherTransferCount;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
{
    public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION BasicLimitInformation;
    public IO_COUNTERS IoInfo;
    public UIntPtr ProcessMemoryLimit;
    public UIntPtr JobMemoryLimit;
    public UIntPtr PeakProcessMemoryUsed;
    public UIntPtr PeakJobMemoryUsed;
}
```

, и регистрировать с помощью него процессы Excel как дочерние:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
int processId;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(app.Hwnd, out processId);
ChildProcessTracker.AddProcess(processId);
```

, и тогда ОС будет убивать их вместе с родительским процессом.

Рекоммендую ознакомиться с документацией и почитать комментарии в обсуждении по ссылке, могут возникнуть нюансы с поддержкой разных версий ОС и Visual Studio, при запуске с ограниченными правами, при запуске родительского приложения из других процессов.

> Если нет, то можно ли понять при запуске(повторном) приложения, что в процессах висит мусор, который остался от прошлого запуска и грохнуть эти процессы, не затронув реальные приложения офиса(например, юзер запустил Excel.)

Сомневаюсь в существовании надежного метода. Процесс Excel запущенный старым процессом ничем не отличается от процесса запущенного текущим/другими приложениями/пользователем. Можно, как предложил @VadimTagil,  написать код, который будет сохранять запущенные процессы в постоянное хранилище (диск/БД/реестр) и убивать их по определенной логике. Еще один вариант, вынести формирование Excel в отдельные процессы-задания, не зависящие от основного приложения.

Вообще, если в нормальном ходе работы приложения мусор не остается, то проблемы будут возникать лишь в исключительных случаях (убитый извне процесс), обработку которых можно будет оставить пользователю. Убедитесь, что для всех объектов вызывается [`Marshal.ReleaseComObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx) и что все процессы завершаются и, возможно, без задания можно будет обойтись.

Comment: Мощная штука. Странно, что обертку под Net не сделали из коробки

Comment: @iluxa1810 Да, с одной стороны пожалели ресурсов, с другой есть отличия между разными версиями Windows. Вообще многому что касается управления процессами нет «managed» альтернативы.

Comment: Хмм, а вот это не является оберткой над тем, что вы описали https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853426(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 не работал с этим, поэтому точно сказать не могу. Судя по [описанию HPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff976568.aspx) это пакет для серверных кластеров.

Answer (score 2):

Я полагаю, суть вопроса в методике отделения "мусора" от нормальных процессов Excel. Умея это, уже можно что-то смастерить: удалять мусорные процессы при запуске основной программы, или периодически - фоновым сервисом, когда основная программа закрыта.

Наиболее правильное решение: добавлять Id всех создаваемых Interop-процессов в БД, при корректном их завершении - удалять. Соответственно, при некорректном завершении приложения в БД останутся Id мертвых процессов, которые можно на следующем запуске прибить (предварительно убедившись, что это все еще существующие процессы Excel, так как они могли быть прибиты чем-то другим и те же Id уже переиспользованы системой для другой программы).

Но, если хочется метод попроще, можно считать "мусором" любой процесс Excel, не имеющий видимого главного окна:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class Program 
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    public static bool IsProcessDead(Process pr)
    {
            IntPtr hwnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;
            if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) return true;

            return !IsWindowVisible(hwnd);            
    }



    void ClearProcesses()
    {                
            Process[] prs=Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
            foreach (Process proc in prs)
            {
                if(IsProcessDead(proc))proc.Kill();
            }
     }

}
```

Если на целевой машине нет других программ, использующих невидимые эксели для своих целей, это можно считать нормальным допущением.

Comment: А если есть невидимые экскли , которые что то делают в других программах? Можно ли узнать его отцовский процесс и если его уже нет, то прибить?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Можно, через функции  Process32First и Process32Next, см. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx Но это сомнительно, так как при завершении процесса значение его id может быть выдано системой другому вновь созданному процессу. И не факт что поле "родительский процесс" у всех дочерних процессов автоматически обнуляется. Лучше запоминать id своих процессов, если не хочется прибивать лишнего.

Comment: вроде, не обязательно этими винапи функциями пользоваться. Вроде, список процессов можно через пространство диагностики получить. Запись id в бд не панацея... а вдруг юзер руками прибьёт excel процесс? -> какая то новая программа может начать Нэтом id.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Я не нашел как средствами .net определить. "а вдруг юзер руками прибьёт excel процесс? -> какая то новая программа может начать Нэтом id" - прибивать только Excel процессы. Вероятность того, что новый id будет тоже выдан именно экселю, все таки довольно мала.